# How to replace "\" to "T" using regex?

Tags: regex, vb.net

```
 Dim str = "this \1 \a is tag \t, this is \ tag \n"
```

I want replace character `"\"` to character `"T"`, but not replace `"\"` of `"\t"` and `"\n"`.

How replace `"\"` to `"T"` by regex and not replace `"\"` of `"\t"` and `"\n"`?

Comment: Your string literal doesn't make any sense. If it's Java, the code won't compile.

Comment: I'm sorry. i using vb.net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following regexp to **find all `\` signs except for `\n`, `\t`, `\r` escaping characters:**

```
\\(?![tnr])
```

That's how you can do this in VB.NET:

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim input As String = "this \1 \a is tag \t, this is \ tag \n"
        Dim output As String = Regex.Replace(input, "\\(?![tnr])", "T")

        Console.WriteLine(output)
    End Sub    
End Module
```

Working [IDEOne VB.NET demo](http://ideone.com/7Zr7AL).

Comment: i want keep "\" of "\t" and "\n".

Comment: @DT Check this demo out: https://regex101.com/r/mR0aA7/1 and http://ideone.com/5EpSuF

Comment: i only want not replace of "\t" and "\n", but \1,\a still want replace.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex would be

```
"(\\[^tn]?)\s"
```

and replace `T`. You didn't say which language, but [here](https://regex101.com/r/nG2hG2/) is a demo of the regex working.

Comment: I'm sorry. i only want not replace "\" of "\t" and "\n", but \1,\a still want replace.

Comment: Err, right. Well, the regex is updated as is the demo. Now it will match any slash not followed by `t` or `n`.